# Transparent objects appearing

Tags: html, css

I've got several divs with `display: inline-block`

```
<div style="width:48%;padding:3px;z-index:1;" class="main_block">
    Text :<br>
    <div style="width:100%;border:1px solid #f7f7f7;background-color:#f7f7f7;height:150px;overflow:visible;">
        <div style="width:100%;" id="main_contact_us">
            Looong text here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The divs are arranged horizontally, but sometimes I need the 2nd div in each group to become `overflow: visible`, and when I do that on `mouseover`, the 3rd div will be displayed UNDER any divs below the main divs group and it is TRANSPARENT! This means I can see any text underneath it and I cannot set a background color for it. Is there any solution?

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/r9ERu/).

Comment: Looks fine to me...how is it supposed to be? I don't see what you are describing.....

Comment: when a div overflow becomes 'visible' i want the content of that div to be ON TOP of everything , z-order is not working + the content is transparent (i can see text of other objects underneath it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added `position:relative;` to the inner div and everything worked fine

Comment: you didn't specify, but let me guess.... this was an IE problem, right? gotta love IE's little bugs; they get ya every time.

Comment: Actually it was on chrome , i don't think it's a bug (because chrome doesn't have them :p) if it was IE , i wouldn't have replied to your comment because the PC would have been flying in the air hehe